# Plot variation in heave v/s speed v/s change in mass in one graph?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, dynamics

So I am trying to plot variation in Heave (**Z-direction**) of three ships with a change in its **Speed** (which is in Froude number i.e. non-dimensionalized) and change in its **Draft** (mass).

What's the best way to visualized this in one graph/plot? This is for my research work.

Thank you for your time.

[image: Graph this]

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you should try to be consistent in the decimal places in each column and for same measures. Do you need to plot this like that? I mean you could try a dimensional analysis. It seems like you have mass, velocity, g, heave, a characteristic length and density in your problem. And by the Pi-Theorem you can create 3 dimensionless parameters. That should make plotting significantly easier.

Comment: try plotting things in various ways untill you find something that best illustrates the point you are trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you 3D data (draft, speed, heave) that you have to repeat for each ship.

[image]